# React Progressbar not Visible?

Tags: reactjs, progress-bar

I have created a React progress bar with the help of third part library

```
import React from "react";
import { css } from "@emotion/core";
import ClipLoader from "react-spinners/ClipLoader";
 
 
// Can be a string as well. Need to ensure each key-value pair ends with ;
const override = css`
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-color: red;
`;
 
class AwesomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true
    };
  }
 
  render() {
    return (
        
      <div className="sweet-loading">
        <ClipLoader
          css={override}
          size={150}
          color={"#123abc"}
          loading={this.state.loading}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default AwesomeComponent;
```

and then import in **index.js** file

```
import AwesomeComponent from './awesomeComponent.js';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
      <AwesomeComponent />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

In my application i want to show this progresbar when data loading from nodejs api or any button clicked ..But nothing visible in GUI related to progressbar.

Comment: usePromiseTracker is react-hook? Perhaps you need to use function component instead of class

Comment: @RamanNikitsenka Yes But sorry that was not used anywhere in code.Edited the code base as well.

Comment: I've created an example for coping your code above and I see the spinner there. https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-monad-4tipc?file=/src/AwesomeComponent.js. Could you please describe what behavior are you expecting?

Comment: @RamanNikitsenka Thanks for your example...What i am trying to do ..Each rest request or button/link clicked show spinner so user should know some process going on.

Comment: @SudobhJoshi I've updated example and added button that change state
https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-monad-4tipc?file=/src/AwesomeComponent.js

Comment: You can add this as a answer.

Comment: @SubodhJoshi, this is not how `react-promise-tracker` should be used, in that case you need to put the loader each and everyplace and have to pass props everytime

Answer (score 1):

If you are using class based component for `react-promise-tracker` then you need to use HOC `promiseTrackerHoc` :

```
import React from "react";
import { css } from "@emotion/core";
import ClipLoader from "react-spinners/ClipLoader";
import { promiseTrackerHoc } from "react-promise-tracker"; // <--------- HERE
  
// Can be a string as well. Need to ensure each key-value pair ends with ;
const override = css`
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-color: red;
`;
 
class AwesomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true
    };
  }
 
  render() {
    return (
        this.props.promiseInProgress && // <--------- HERE
        <div className="sweet-loading">
            <ClipLoader
            css={override}
            size={150}
            color={"#123abc"}
            loading={this.state.loading}
            />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default promiseTrackerHoc(AwesomeComponent); // <--------- HERE
```

**WORKING DEMO :**

[image: Edit #SO-promise-tracker]

> **Note :**
>
> You can checkout **[DOC](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-promise-tracker)**, as they have explained everything, I
> think you can help you to find out whatever the scenario you want to
> implement

Comment: Thanks for your answer suppose i wont use `react-promise-tracker` at all in code base in that case only this much code will not work? Actully what i am trying to achieve each button/link click or data load should automatically support Spinner..You answer giving `Line 24:9:  'props' is not defined  no-undef`

Comment: @SubodhJoshi, this is code for spinner/loader this is just one time code, then all you need is use `trackPromise`, wherever you need to show loader you have to put that, and sorry I missed `this` before `props`,

Comment: Thanks i am new in rectjs..In JSF we have facility add one common place Spinner it will work for all the other pages so i was looking for same.

Comment: @SubodhJoshi, please once go through this once , https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-promise-tracker, I think this will clear all your doubts.

Comment: So you mean  after writing a component i have to  `import { trackPromise } from 'react-promise-tracker';` and add `promiseTrackerHoc` in each the js file where i want to show the Spinner?

Comment: `promiseTrackerHoc` is just for one time, and `trackPromise` will trigger the the loader automatically, just check `trackPromise` inside `app.js` in demo, hope that will clear your doubts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216324/discussion-between-subodh-joshi-and-vivek-doshi).

Answer (score 1):

In this example, you can see how you can change the visibility of your spinner just changed the local state by clicking on button

https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-monad-4tipc?file=/src/AwesomeComponent.js